# How do I change ok cancel option of bootbox to yes & no?

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I want to change ok cancel option of bootbox to yes & no. I have tried my solutions but still show the default one. Here is my button.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary but-style-left" ng-click="saveForLaterClick(this)">{{ResourceData.Cancel}}</button>
```

This is my `.js` file code

```
$scope.saveForLaterClick = function (e) {

    confirmClaimMessage($scope.ResourceData.RenewalProductAreYouSureWantToContinueText, function (e) {
        if (e) {
            window.open("#/Renewal", "_self");
        }
    });

}

function confirmClaimMessage(text, callback) {
bootbox.confirm(text, function (e) {
    callback(e);
});
```

I am expecting this

```
bootbox.confirm({
        message: $scope.ResourceData.RenewalProductAreYouSureWantToContinueText,
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: $scope.ResourceData.PoppupYesText                   
            },
            cancel: {
                label: $scope.ResourceData.PoppupNoText                    
            }
        },
        callback: function (e) {
            if (e) {
                window.open("#/Renewal", "_self");
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me!